# Rails Logs - Filter By IP of Request and Session

Tags: logs, log-analysis

I am searching for a Rails Logging Solution which allows me to filter by IP Address and/or Session. When a particular 'user' has a problem, I want to be able to view only the log entries pertaining to their activity.  I am using the web-brick server.

Looking at the cloud-tools out there, they seem geared for multiple servers and this is not included in their feature-lists. I only have one server, and this is the primary-feature I need.

When I do web-searches for "rails log" + "filter by ip" and similar terms, I get next to no results / ancient pages containing dead-links. I know there must be a product/service for this - no need for me to write something from scratch - but where?